# fuzzy wuzzy token sort vs difflib Sequence matcher

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, sequencematcher

I am trying to figure out the difference between the two.
I get the same results(similarity scores) using the two for the same strings.

1. Can somebody please explain the difference between the two using the formula for each of them?
2. Any idea if one is faster than the other?

[image]

Comment: It would appear that fuzzy wuzzy makes use of difflib for some of its functionality; refer https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/af443f918eebbccff840b86fa606ac150563f466/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py#L12. Which might explain why you are getting similar performance in these use cases.